# How do I access values from a Map object in a loop?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have an object called `dataLookup`, the contents of which are https://pastebin.com/MG4xB8ht.
This is what one item looks like in it:

```js
    {
        "key": "Andaman & Nicobar",
        "value": {
            "state": "Andaman & Nicobar",
            "fcra_registered": 8,
            "total": 140
        }
    },
```

I want to access the `total` value for each `key` and assign that to a prop in another component.
I have this:

```js
z={(d) => dataLookup.get(d["state"])["total"]}
```

This gives me an error:

```js
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Update: I've added a working REPL of the entire issue. You can see the error in the console. [It is here](https://svelte.dev/repl/31462bf121c748feac329590351d4fcc?version=3.53.1), the error occurs on line 62.

Comment: What are `d["state"]` and `dataLookup.get(d["state"])` at the moment of the error?

Comment: @mykaf How do I find that out?

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicates the result you're expecting?

Comment: Do you know how to use `console.log()`?

Comment: How are you add the data to the map?

Comment: @David I've added a REPL, would that be good enough?

Comment: @Andy there's an update with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`LayerCake`](https://layercake.graphics/guide/#getting-started) is expecting an array of objects so a `Map` isn't really going to help here. Based on the documentation you should probably get an array of objects each of which comprises just its value object:

```
const dataLookup = arr.map(obj => obj.value);
```

And then add that array to the Svelte component:

```
<LayerCake
  data={dataLookup}
  // etc
</LayerCake>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was that two keys were misplaced (`Odisha` vs `Orissa`). It has been corrected and the above code is correct.

Additionally, I added in `?.[colorKey]` instead of `[colorKey]` in this scenario so it doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

```
let list = [{
        "state": "Andaman & Nicobar",
        "fcra_registered": 8,
        "total": 140
}]

 let map1 = new Map()
 list.map(item => map1.set(item.state,item.total))

console.log(map1.get('Andaman & Nicobar'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please see my updated question? I've added a Repl with fuller code. How would I implement your answer in my code?

Comment: Your JSON what u shared in question is different from the structure in REPL provided by you. Also why are you trying to push into map using dataJoinKey and trying to get from Map using mapJoinKey ?